# yii2 name field attribute using variable

Tags: yii, yii2, field, active-form

I'm trying to create in an activeform a series of controls using a loop for not being to declare the various fields of the model in order to have a generic template to which I pass only the name of the table and it creates the edit form.
So that if I pass the table A and it has 3 fields it creates three fields, the b has 5 fields it creates 5 fields etc etc.

**$tfields= Array ( [0] => id [1] => brand_id [2] => group_id)**
and i create this code

```
foreach($tfields as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($value)>0){
 echo $form->field($model,  $value)->textInput();
}
  }
```

but when i run the code i get this error

**Calling unknown method: yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::isAttributeRequired()**

any ideas?
tks a lot!

Comment: Error is from activeDataProvider. update question with missing details. what is in current file and controller.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was tha i use an ActiveDataProvider as model, using instead  and DynamicModel

in the controller

```
$model2= new \yii\base\DynamicModel([
   ]);
```

in the form

```
 foreach(explode(',',$fields) as $item){
    if (strlen($item)<>0){ //to avoid empty 
   echo $form->field($model2, $item)->textInput();
     }
  }
```